# How to completely remove back button from navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

For some reason I'm adding left and right buttons to the navigation bar as its subview instead of using navigation item. When pushing a view controller, I'm setting its `navigationItem.hidesBackButton` to `YES` so that the ugly looking blue 'back' button will not show up. The problem I'm facing is that, after tapping my own back button, while the currently showing view controller being popped --- I mean during the animation of the 'pop', I can see a '...' in the navigation bar moving right along with the popped view controller. And, I DON'T want that '...' to appear for even 0.0000000001 second. What may I do now? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are adding your custom buttons you can do something like [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIView alloc] init]]];

Comment: if you are using storyboard , set navigationBar tint clear colour in NavigationController.

Comment: Use `self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = Yes` instead.

Comment: @Sushil It doesn't work. Yes I'm using storyboard.

Comment: @AdeelMiraj I have a subclassed navigationcontroller and it's been set to the class of the navigationcontrollers in storyboard. And I tried setting self.navigationItem.hideBackButton in my custom navigationcontroller. But it didn't work.

Comment: @harshayarabarla The reason I'm not doing that way is that I want my back button have no padding to the left edge of the screen. Is there a way to change the position of navigationItem?

Comment: @Sabbath For that you can modify image insets of bar item in size inspector of `barButtonItem`.

Comment: try this : self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil

Comment: @Krupanshu I've tried this. Didn't work.

Comment: you add your own back button right ? What its Type ? Its CUSTOM of SYSTEM ? If there is any text for button then try after removing the title

Comment: please post the code / or snap how you added your own back button.

Comment: @Sushil Sorry, I said that changing navigation bar tint color did not work. That was wrong. By doing that, the naughty '...' is now disappeared! Thank you for the help. If you write the answer below, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Sabbath, great. I posted it as answer.Please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Sushil Done. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:Problem solved with just comment. But posting this as answer so that It will help someone else having same issue.**

I too had same problem with `navigationBarButtonItem` while adding custom `barButtonItem` to `navigationBar` in storyboard. If you are also using storyboard then just set `navigationBar` tint color as clear color in `navigationController`. By setting clear color, that weird default navigation back button will not appear anymore.